# Recursion inside ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, math, awt

I have to add add recursion inside ActionListener to calculate fibonacci sequence of a given number, i've tried to add recursion in this way, but it didn't work.

```
        fibonacci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText());
                if(a == 0)
                    result.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                else if(a == 1)
                    result.setText(String.valueOf("1"));
                else
                result.setText(String.valueOf(fibonacci(a - 1) + fibonacci(a - 2)));
                } catch (Exception f) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR: " + (f.getMessage()));
                }
            String aField = input1.getText();
            if (e.getSource() == fibonacci) {
                if ("".equals(aField)) {
                    String emptyFieldWarning;
                    emptyFieldWarning = "One or more fields is/are empty!";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, emptyFieldWarning);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursion should happen within it's own method, the `ActionListener` should stand as the initiation of that recursion.

Something along the lines of

```
fibonacci.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String fibonacciStr = fibonacciRecursion(0, 1, 10);
        }
}

String fibonacciRecursion(int value0, int value1, int depth){
    StringBuilder fibStr = new StringBuilder();
    if(depth > 0){
        fibStr.append(fibonacciRecursion(value1, value0 + value1, depth-1));
    }
    return fibStr;
}
```

As you didn't mention any limit, the depth parameter is meant so your recursion has a way of stopping, as to avoid a SO.

I haven't tested this, but it should be enough to get you closer to a solution of your own design.

**Edit**

As per @Tom Hawtin - tackline 's comment, this can also be done via lambda expression

```
fibonacci.addActionListener(actionEvent-> 
    System.our.println(fibonacciRecursion(0, 1, 10)));
```

Comment: (Not a great use of `StringBuilder`. Also go use a lambda instead of an anonymous inner class for an `ActionListener`. (Method references wont work because of the unhelpful event parameter.))

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Great suggestions I figured a string would work just as well, but had heard StringBuilder was more efficient. I'd have done something better in my code.